# Deploying Communities

Tags: community

Search around online but haven't been able to find much information on the subject.  What is the deployment process for Communities?

Say I build out a Community on a Dev Org.  What is the process for moving it to UT?  Production?

Are there any special considerations I need to make? For example, can the name/url of my community transfer to production?  Or do I need to make sure not to use the desired URL for my production community in a dev environment?

Comment: You can use the [Network](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_network.htm) meta data type to migrate the definition of a community. I would guess you can do this via a change set as well. I'm not sure about your other questions. Hence this is a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: What kind of community are you deploying? Does this community require a particular license? The answer to your questions somewhat depends on that. In your Sandbox, your URL is already different than it is in a Production Org. Generally speaking though, you want to do a test release when you move it to production to make certain everything works rather than opening the doors to everyone. Is there an existing portal already there that you're replacing? I know, lots of questions. ;)

Comment: Also, forgot to ask, have you created an "App" for your community? Doing so can make things much easier during deployment.

Comment: @crmprogdev Those are all good questions and ones I'm not sure I have the answer to yet.  I think need to do some more research and get back to you.